# Shade between vertical curves

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How to shade between the vertical curves `$x=1-y^2$` and `$x=y^3-y$` and the horizontals **$y=0.7$ and $y=-0.5$**?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{every x tick label/.append style={font=\tiny, yshift=0.5ex}}
\pgfplotsset{every y tick label/.append style={font=\tiny, xshift=0.5ex}}
\pgfplotsset{every axis plot/.append style={ thick}}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.misc}
\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/axis labels at tip/.style={
    xlabel style={at={(current axis.right of origin)}, xshift=1.5ex, anchor=center},
    ylabel style={at={(current axis.above origin)}, yshift=1.5ex, anchor=center}}
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[scale=1,
axis on top=true,      
      axis lines=middle,
      axis line style={thick,-latex},
      y=3cm,
    x=3cm,
restrict y to domain=-2:2,
restrict x to domain=-0.5:1,
      xmin=-1.5,xmax=1.5,
      ymin=-1.5,ymax=1.5,
      xlabel=$x$, 
      ylabel=$y$,
axis labels at tip,
      xtick={-2,...,2},
      ytick={-2,...,2},
] 
\addplot [name path=E,very thick,DodgerBlue4,domain=-0.7:0.9,samples=200] ({1-x^2},{x});
\addplot [name path=D,very thick,Chartreuse4,domain=-0.7:0.9,samples=100] ({x^3-x},{x});
\addplot[name path=A,mark=none,gray] coordinates {(0.51,0.7) (-0.357,0.7)};
\addplot[name path=B,mark=none,gray] coordinates {(0.75,-0.5) (0.375,-0.5)};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome! You can do that with the `soft clip={domain y=-0.5:0.7}` key,

```
\addplot[red!20] fill between[of=E and D,soft clip={domain y=-0.5:0.7}];
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{every x tick label/.append style={font=\tiny, yshift=0.5ex}}
\pgfplotsset{every y tick label/.append style={font=\tiny, xshift=0.5ex}}
\pgfplotsset{every axis plot/.append style={ thick}}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.misc}
\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/axis labels at tip/.style={
    xlabel style={at={(current axis.right of origin)}, xshift=1.5ex, anchor=center},
    ylabel style={at={(current axis.above origin)}, yshift=1.5ex, anchor=center}}
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[scale=1,
    axis on top=true,      
          axis lines=middle,
          axis line style={thick,-latex},
          y=3cm,
        x=3cm,
    restrict y to domain=-2:2,
    restrict x to domain=-0.5:1,
          xmin=-1.5,xmax=1.5,
          ymin=-1.5,ymax=1.5,
          xlabel=$x$, 
          ylabel=$y$,
    axis labels at tip,
          xtick={-2,...,2},
          ytick={-2,...,2},
] 
   \addplot [name path=E,very thick,DodgerBlue4,domain=-0.7:0.9,samples=200] ({1-x^2},{x});
   \addplot [name path=D,very thick,Chartreuse4,domain=-0.7:0.9,samples=100] ({x^3-x},{x});
   \addplot[red!20] fill between[of=E and D,soft clip={domain y=-0.5:0.7}];
   \addplot[name path=A,mark=none,gray] coordinates {(0.51,0.7) (-0.357,0.7)};
   \addplot[name path=B,mark=none,gray] coordinates {(0.75,-0.5) (0.375,-0.5)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok...I didn't think of the y=... in the softclip domain.